# ApexRest JSON Parser error when calling Salesforce webservice saying unexpected parameter using through iOS

Tags: ios, web-services, salesforce, apex-code

In calling apexrest webservice for uploading attachment to specific record by calling method. So for this I hardcoded Json.

```
-(void)uploadToSalesforce
{   
    NSData *imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagePreview.image, 1.0);
    int datalength = [imagedata length];

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Supload_iPhone_%d.jpg",datalength];

    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n\"name\":\"%@\",\n\"Body\": \"%@\"\n,\"ParenId\":%@\"\n}",filename,imagedata,receivedrecordid];
    const char *utfString = [req UTF8String];
    NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes:utfString length:strlen(utfString)];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];  
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestUrl = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init ];
    [requestUrl setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/services/apexrest/Account/",receivedinstanceurl]]];
    [requestUrl setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [requestUrl setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [requestUrl setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",receivedaccesstoken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [requestUrl setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [requestUrl setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *reponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestUrl returningResponse:&response  error:&err];
    NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:reponseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

In response it says there is

```
[{"message":"Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: Name at [line:2, column:9]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
```

In console JSON seems correct but cannot parse parameter "Name".I think this is not by IOS code. Or is there some different format.

Comment: JSON was wrongly formed.

Comment: Did you get any resolution for this ?

Comment: @DivineDesert Yes I solved it a long time ago. This happened because of incorrect json building by code. Do you need help?

Comment: Can you post your answer to the very Post so that others also get solution in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n\"name\":\"%@\",\n\"Body\": \"%@\"\n,\"ParenId\":%@\"\n}",filename,imagedata,receivedrecordid];
```

JSON is missing `"` character for `ParentId` key value. It should be:

```
NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n\"name\":\"%@\",\n\"Body\": \"%@\"\n,\"ParenId\":\"%@\"\n}",filename,imagedata,receivedrecordid];
```

Therefore Salesforce webservice deserialization was throwing exception.